# Logical consequences, universal closure, substitution, first-order logic, unification

Tags: substitution, unification, first-order-logic

Who can help me to show that:

The universal closure of an instance of a formula F is a logical consequence of the universal closure of F.

```
 i.e., Show that ∀F |= ∀(Fθ), where
       F: a formula
       θ: a substitution
```

Thanks.

Comment: This seems very much off-topic on Stack Overflow itself. You should probably try http://cs.stackexchange.com instead.